# Entity Framework is not working in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework is not working in Entity Framework 5.

Department class:

```
 public partial class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Budget { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> InstructorID { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Course class:

```
  public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Enrollments = new HashSet<Enrollment>();
        this.People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public byte[] rowversion { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Even Lazy loading and ProxyCreationEnabled are set to true. Please help me out